# How to move an event from one linked list to another

Tags: java, linked-list, nodes, simulation

I am working on a project for my Simulation class that revolves around an airport simulation. The objective is that events arrive at different stations or the terminal, and I need the bus to take the events to their correct destination. I can create the events and place them in their correct terminal. The place I am having problems is moving an event from one linked list to another.

For example, if an event shows up at Station A, I need it to get on the Bus, and get off at the Terminal.

```
while(passengers < 200){

     /*
     * This first section is where I create my events and place 
     * them in their appropriate places.
     */


    Random ran = new Random();
    int x = ran.nextInt(4) + 1;

    for(int i = 1; i <= x; i++){

    //passengers arrival time
        double U = random.nextFloat();
        double nextArrival =  -(Math.log(U))/lambda;    
    //double nextDeparture = -(Math.log(U))/mu;

    //determines place of origin and destination
        Random r = new Random();
        int randnum = r.nextInt(places.length);
        int randnum1 = r.nextInt(places.length - 1);
        String o = places[randnum];
        String d;
        if(o.equalsIgnoreCase("Terminal") ) d = places[randnum1];
        else d = places[3];

    //creates new event
        Event a = new Event(nextArrival, o, d);

    //place event at origin
        if(o.equalsIgnoreCase("StationA")){
            StationA.insert(a);
            StationA.curSize++;
        }
        else if(o.equalsIgnoreCase("StationB")){
            StationB.insert(a);
            StationB.curSize++;
        }
        else if(o.equalsIgnoreCase("StationC")){
            StationC.insert(a);
            StationC.curSize++;
        }
        else {
            Terminal.insert(a);
            Terminal.curSize++;
        }


        passengers++;

    }

    /*
     * Now bus has to go to all stations and terminal
     */

    //BUS GOES TO STATION A
    //people have to get off bus first

    if(Bus.isEmpty()) break;
    else {
        while(StationA.curSize != StationA.limit){
            boolean w = Bus.findEventTF("StationA");
            if(w = true){
                //find an event that needs to get off bus
                Event a = Bus.findEvent("StationA");
                //place event stationa completed list
                CompletedA.addLast(a);
                //increase current size of stationa completed list
                CompletedA.curSize++;
                //remove event from bus
                Bus.delete(a);
                //decrease current size of bus list
                Bus.curSize--;
            }
        }
    }

    //people have to get on bus from station a

    if(StationA.isEmpty()) break;
    else {
        while(Bus.curSize != Bus.limit){
            boolean w = Bus.findEventTF("Terminal");
            if(w = true){
                //find an event that needs to get on bus
                Event a = StationA.findEvent("Terminal");
                //place event on bus
                Bus.addLast(a);
                //increase current size of bus
                Bus.curSize++;
                //remove event from StationA
                StationA.delete(a);
                //decrease current size of stationa
                StationA.curSize--;
            }
        }
    }

    /*
     * 
     * Right now im trying to work on Station A and Terminal
     * before i add Station B & C
     * 
     */

    //BUS GOES TO TERMINAL
    //people have to get off bus first

    if(Bus.isEmpty()) break;
    else {
        while(Terminal.curSize != Terminal.limit){
            boolean w = Bus.findEventTF("Terminal");
            if(w = true){
                //find an event that needs to get off bus
                Event a = Bus.findEvent("Terminal");
                //place event terminal completed list
                CompletedT.addLast(a);
                //increase current size of terminal completed list
                CompletedT.curSize++;
                //remove event from bus
                Bus.delete(a);
                //decrease current size of bus list
                Bus.curSize--;
            }
        }
    }

    //people have to get on bus from terminal

    if(Terminal.isEmpty()) break;
    else {
        while(Bus.curSize != Bus.limit){
            //boolean w = Bus.findEventTFTerm('S');
            if(Bus.findEventTFTerm('S') = true){
                //find an event that needs to get on bus
                Event a = StationA.findEventTerm('S');
                //place event on bus
                Bus.addLast(a);
                //increase current size of bus
                Bus.curSize++;
                //remove event from StationA
                Terminal.delete(a);
                //decrease current size of terminal
                Terminal.curSize--;
            }
        }
    }

}
```

If I do the first part alone it works, when I try to move things around it doesnt. Any help would be greatly appreciated. If you would like me to add the code from my linked list class let me know. Thanks.

Comment: Off topic, but you might want to read a [java style guide](https://google.github.io/styleguide/javaguide.html) because it seems like some of your lists/objects start with capital letters. This makes it confusing for people to read because the convention is that all variables start with lowercase letters and all classes start with uppercase letters, to help with readability.

Comment: It'll help to define what the problem is a bit more - what is working and what isn't? What have you tried? What steps have worked and what do you expect should happen but doesn't?

Comment: It looks like `Terminal`, `StationA`, `StationB` are variables (and should be named `terminal, stationA, stationB` as Matt pointed out) but I don't see declarations for them so we don't know what type(s) they are... some kind of "List"? A class that you wrote? (why not use java.util.LinkedList?) If it's yours, you shouldn't have to do `StationA.curSize++` — `StationA.insert(a)` should take care of incrementing the size and `.delete(a)` should decrement it. Anyway, your error might be in that, so you should also include that source in your question.

Comment: As i mentioned in the original post, the terminal, bus and the stations are all linked lists. And i created my own linkedlist class for this as well. **I want to move an event from a station to the bus, and then move the event from the bus to the terminal.** That is what I am trying to figure out. I initialized everything, i just didnt include it cause i there is alot of code.

Comment: Be careful with nomenclature, vocabulary shapes our thinking and misuse can lead to miscommunication and faulty logic.  Your usage of "event" is non-standard to an extreme.  In simulation modeling, an event is a point in time at which the system state changes.  I suspect you should be using "person" or "customer" everywhere you say "event".